# what is meant by 'Most C system provide for logically infinite floating values'?

Tags: c, precision, divide-by-zero, format-specifiers

Initially I declared variables x and y as type int:

```
#include<stdio.h>   

     int main(){
        int x, y = 0 ;
        x = 1 / y;
        printf("%d", x);

        return 0;    
    }
```

Program crashed (for obvious reasons).

Now I declared variables x and y as double:

```
#include<stdio.h>   

 int main(){
    double x, y = 0 ;
    x = 1 / y;
    printf("%d", x);

    return 0;    
}
```

But Output: 0. (why?)

Then I changed %d to %f in printf:

```
#include<stdio.h>   

 int main(){
    double x, y = 0 ;
    x = 1 / y;
    printf("%f", x);

    return 0;    
}
```

Output: 1.#INF00

I don't understand what is happening here.

Please explain me above cases.

Comment: Please enable compiler warnings. in the second code snippet, `printf("%d", x);` - `x` is type `double`, you can't print it using `%d`...

Comment: The phrase "logically infinite floating value" means there is a particular binary representation used to indicate that the value is infinite, instead of the usual exponent-significand format. This does not happen with integer types. In the case of integer divide by zero, the processor generates a fault. In the case of floating point, the overflow condition is intercepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no numbers in a computer. We build computers out of physical parts, and we use physical properties to store and manipulate data.

In various places, a computer has electric charges, electric voltages, magnetic fields, or other physical things that we use to represent data. In doing this, we pick some physical state and call it “0” and some other state and call it “1”. These are merely convenient names. Mathematical numbers like 0 and 1 are abstract entities—they are concepts with no physical existence. The numbers 0 and 1 do not exist in computers.

We bundle these physical states, often in groups of eight, 32, or 64, and then label them in various ways. For example, with the eight bits in the states labeled 00100010, we might call that “34”. It is still not a number. We are merely using a binary notation for the number 34, and that binary notation further designates the state of the pieces of the machine.

The pieces of the machine in the state 00100010 are not inherently the actual number 34 any more than they are a banana or the concept of red.

We design parts of the machine so they can manipulate these states. Somewhere in the machine is an *adder* that takes as input physical states representing one number and physical states representing another number and creates as output physical states representing the number that is the sum of the two input numbers.

Computers contain many parts like these that create the effect of adding numbers, multiplying numbers, subtracting numbers, and so on. These are just effects created in a machine.

With floating-point numbers, we designate certain of the bit patterns to represent infinity, and we design the floating-point arithmetic unit to behave correspondingly. When we give the floating-point arithmetic adder one input that represents infinity and another input that represents a finite number, it produces an output that represents infinity, because we designed the floating-point arithmetic unit to do that. Similarly, when we give the floating-point divider one input that represents the number one and another input that represents the number zero, it produces as output the bit pattern that represents infinity, again because we designed it to do that.

When you print a floating-point object that as the bit pattern representing infinity using `printf("%f", x);`, the C implementation prints a string representing infinity. Microsoft’s chosen string for that is “1.#INF00”, which is rather ugly. Some other implementations use “inf”, which is only slightly better.

When you attempt to print a floating-point object using `printf("%d", x);`, the behavior is not defined by the C standard, because the `%d` conversion expects to receive an `int` object, but the `x` you are passing is a `double` object. Passing the wrong type of argument can screw up the argument-passing mechanism in a variety of ways, so you will not always get answers that make sense without knowing how the internals of the software work.

Comment: **thanks a ton sir, perfect and beautiful answer i say**

Answer (score 6):

Most systems you're likely to come in contact with use [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) representation for floating point numbers.  That representation has ways to store the values +infinity and -infinity.

While strictly speaking, dividing by 0 is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), implementations using IEEE 754 extend the language to allow it for floating point types.  In this case, dividing by 0 can be considered infinity, so your implementation allows it, and `1.#INF00` is how MSVC prints the value for infinity.

Also, using the wrong format specifier for printing as in your second example where you use `%d` to print a `double` is undefined behavior.  Format specifiers must match the datatype of what is passed in.

Comment: To extend dbush's excellent answer: you have dealt with the extreme cases. Floating point arithmetic will start to give you problems long before it gives you errors. Be sure that you understand the IEEE 754 standard and the implications of running out of space and dropping least significant bits in calculations. Integer arithmetic is exact, floating point is not necessarily so.